# Mobile app performance analysis (Appium + Ruby)

Tags: ruby, mobile, appium, performance-testing

I was wondering if there is any opensource framework for mobile app performance testing that uses Appium with preferably Ruby.
Thank you

I've only found commercial tools for mobile app performance analysis so far. I'm expecting to find a opensource framework.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to assess mobile application performance per se like loading speed, resources consumption, rendering speed, switching between views, etc. - you should rather consider using profiler tools which are normally supplied by your mobile operating system vendor, for example:

- [Instruments for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/411)
- [Android Studio Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile)

In case you need to test performance of the **backend**, to wit simulate hundreds or thousands of the mobile application users concurrently doing what they're supposed to be doing the better option would be simulating network footprint of the mobile application and replaying it with increased number of threads (virtual users). In this case you will need a load testing tool which supports [network protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) used by the mobile application. A list of free and open source load testing tools including highlighting of main features and comparison can be found in i.e. [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools)